# Selenium-java : Access zip file inside a container

Tags: java, selenium, containers, zip

I am running my selenium-java testcases inside a container. In one of the tests, I have to download a zip file. I want to navigate to the download zip file and read the content inside zip file

```
String Path = "/home/Downloads/Test.zip";

zipFile = new ZipFile(Path);
```

When I run the test, I get "java.io.FileNotFoundException: \home\Downloads\Test.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)"

My question is why are forward-slash converted into backslash and how can I access the zip file inside the container

I have also tried with URI but still the forward-slashes in the path are replaced by back slash

```
 URI uri = path.toUri();
 System.out.println("uri is "+uri.getPath().substring(3));
```

Comment: Can you check wether you are able to access the file manually on the container?

Comment: Yes I am able to access it manually on the container